# ssh to AWS EC2 Instance with Docker (Ubuntu 14.04) gets Connection Closed by ip port 22

Tags: ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2, ssh

After creating a new AWS EC2 Instance with Docker (Ubuntu AMI), an ssh to it fails with Conenction Closed.

```
ssh -i ~/cmec2-1.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-183-133-180.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Connection closed by 54.183.133.180 port 22
```

I stopped and started the instance 2 times but same error.

Any ideas why this is happening ?

SSH is in the inbound rules

Comment: You could start debugging with `-v` flag, as in `ssh -v -i ~/cmec2-1.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-183-133-180.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], [sf], or [su] instead of here. Aside from that, your best bet is to get into the ec2 instance and see what the ssh server is logging when it drops these connections.